# com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException is thrown while sending email

Tags: java

I have written this java code for sending email but this code is throwing an exception
(com.sun.mail.util.MailConnectException: Couldn't connect to host, port: localhost, 25; timeout -1;
  nested exception is:)
please help.

```
import java.util.*;
import javax.mail.*;
import javax.mail.internet.*;

public class SendEmail
{
   public static void main(String [] args)
   {    
      String to = "to@gmail.com";
      String from = "from@seecs.edu.pk";
      String host = "localhost";
      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
      properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);
      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);
         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");
         message.setText("This is actual message");
         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }
      catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: you need to configure mail server on your local machine(localhost), if you have configured then its not working properly

Comment: Please tell how mail server is configured?